# textarea fields from lightning-record-view-form overflow when in slds-popover

Tags: lightning-recordviewform, popover

I've got a popover that displays record with long or rich text area fields. Fine in most places except when it's in a popover (that's over ligtning-datatable).
When it has long sentences it wouldn't get wrapped breaking out of popover
[image]

Markup

```
<div class="anchor">
    <section class="slds-popover slds-float_left slds-popover_x-large">
        <div class="slds-p-around_small">
            <lightning-record-view-form object-api-name="Job__c" record-id={job.jobId}>
                <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-gutters_direct-small">
                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1">
                        <lightning-output-field field-name="JobDescription__c">
                        </lightning-output-field>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </lightning-record-view-form>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Some custom css

```
:host .anchor {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
:host .slds-popover {
    position: fixed;
}
:host .slds-popover_x-large {
    width: 45rem;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved by adding `text-wrap: wrap;` to `.anchor`

Comment: Nice. Glad you were able to figure it out.